# python multiprocessing queue implementation

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I'm having trouble understanding how to implement queue into a multiprocessing example below.  Basically, I want the code to:

1) spawn 2 processes (done)

2) split up my id_list into two portions (done)

3) have each process iterate over the list printing out each item, and only close when its done with the list.  I know I have to implement some type of Queueing system, and pass that to each worker, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,Queue
id_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def mp_worker(record):
    try:  
        print record
        sleep(1)
    except: pass
    print "worker closed"

def mp_handler():
    p = Pool(processes = 2) #number of processes
    p.map(mp_worker, id_list)  #devides id_list between 2 processes, defined above
    p.close()
    p.join()

mp_handler()
```

Note - the code prints out "worker closed" 10 times.  Id like for this statement to be printed only twice (once for each worker, after each worker prints out the 5 numbers from id_list)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any particular reason you need your own task queue/chunking implementation rather than the one `pool.map` already provides for you?

Comment: The code is a distilled down version of a scraper (worker) that uses selenium webdriver-when i used pool.map, i couldn't figure out how to assign items from the queue to one, already opened webdriver (per worker).  A queue item would get assigned to the webdriver, webdriver would open, process the queue item, close... then the worker would get relaunched again - this killed my performance, since i had to launch the webdriver for every single queue item. With the solution below, I can launch webdriver once per worker, then pass on queue items to it.  Let me know if there is a better way though.

Comment: See my answer -- the worker processes last as long as the pool does. If the workers are getting relaunched, it's because you're closing and remaking the pool.

Comment: If the trouble is keeping the web driver process open, you can do that by moving the init out of the function itself and into the top level of the module. Then it will run once for each pool worker.

Comment: the trouble was passing on queue items one after another to each worker's webdriver, while it was open.  The solution below accomplishes exactly what i was looking for.  tested and working as expected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me (on Python 3). Instead of using a Pool, I spawn my own two processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep


id_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

queue = Queue()

def mp_worker(queue):

    while queue.qsize() >0 :
        record = queue.get()
        print(record)
        sleep(1)

    print("worker closed")

def mp_handler():

    # Spawn two processes, assigning the method to be executed 
    # and the input arguments (the queue)
    processes = [Process(target=mp_worker, args=(queue,)) for _ in range(2)]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()
        print('Process started')

    for process in processes:
        process.join()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    for id in id_list:
        queue.put(id)

    mp_handler()
```

Although the length of the elements to be processed is hardcoded. But it could be a second input argument to for the mp_worker method.

Comment: Thank you, this does what i was looking for.  Instead of the first     for _ in range(5):  , i replaced it with    while queue.qsize() >0 :    , to get rid of some hardcoding.

Comment: That would definitely work if you make sure that you fill the queue before calling the working processes! Otherwise the processes might find the queue to be empty and exit the loop, while you wanted to feed them some extra input for computation.

Answer (score 1):

The print statement you have there is misleading you -- the worker process *does not* terminate at the end of the function. In fact, the worker processes stay alive until the pool is closed. Additionally, `multiprocessing` already takes care of breaking up the list into chunks and queueing up each task for you.

As for your other question, normally you would pass a callback to `map_async` if you wanted to trigger an asynchronous event upon the entire *list* being completed. Calling once per chunk takes some mucking about with the internals, but if you *really* want to you could:

```
def mapstar_custom(args):
    result = list(map(*args))
    print "Task completed"
    return result
...

pool._map_async(f, x, mapstar_custom, None, None, None).get()
```

---

Edit: we seem to be conflating terminology. When I say worker I mean the processes the pool spawns, whereas you seem to mean the processes Selenium spawns from those processes (which wasn't in your question). Opening the webdriver only once is easy enough: if you have `pool.map(module.task, ...)`, then in `module.py` just do:

```
# ... selenium init here ...

def task(...):
    # ... use webdriver ...
```

The module will only be imported once by the pool workers, no matter how many times you dispatch that task. So the top level init will happen only once.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this question by using Pool and Queue is

```py
    from time import sleep
    from multiprocessing import Pool,Queue
    id_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

    def mp_worker(q):
        try:  
            print(q.get())
            sleep(.1)
        except: pass
        print ("worker closed")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        q = Queue()
        p = Pool(processes = 2) #number of processes
        for x in id_list:
            q.put(x)
        p.map(mp_worker, id_list)  #devides id_list between 2 processes, defined above
```

you must add vaules to Quene by **put** in main section of your code and in the function read the value from Queue by **get**

Comment: If I remove try-except block the execution fails with AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'. So q.get() is inaccessible. q.get takes processes from the queue, so  is it the correct behavior?

Comment: I just correct the code of the question, now it works by Queue. The answer of your question is , The mp_worker() function can take any value and if a non-Queue variable come as input, it does not consider it as a Queue variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the top Google result for `Python Multiprocessing Queue implementation` I'm going to post a slightly more generalized example.

Consider the following script:

```
import time
import math
import pprint

def main():
    print('\n' + 'starting . . .' + '\n')

    startTime = time.time()
    my_list = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
    result_list = []

    for num in my_list:
        result_list.append(squareNum(num))
    # end for

    elapsedTime = time.time() - startTime

    print('result_list: ')
    pprint.pprint(result_list)
    print('\n' + 'program took ' + '{:.2f}'.format(elapsedTime) + ' seconds' + '\n')
# end function

def squareNum(num: float) -> float:
    time.sleep(1.0)
    return math.pow(num, 2)
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This script declares 10 floats, squares them (sleeping for 1 second upon each square to simulate some significant process), then collects the results in a new list.  This takes about 10 seconds to run.

Here is a refactored version using `Multiprocessing` `Process` and `Queue`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import math
from typing import List
import pprint


def main():
    print('\n' + 'starting . . .' + '\n')

    startTime = time.time()
    my_list = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
    result_list = []

    multiProcQueue = Queue()

    processes: List[Process] = []
    for num in my_list:
        processes.append(Process(target=squareNum, args=(num, multiProcQueue,)))
    # end for

    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    # end for

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    # end for

    while not multiProcQueue.empty():
        result_list.append(multiProcQueue.get())
    # end for

    elapsedTime = time.time() - startTime

    print('result_list: ')
    pprint.pprint(result_list)
    print('\n' + 'program took ' + '{:.2f}'.format(elapsedTime) + ' seconds' + '\n')
# end function

def squareNum(num: float, multiProcQueue: Queue) -> None:
    time.sleep(1.0)
    result = math.pow(num, 2)
    multiProcQueue.put(result)
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This script runs in about 1 second.  To my knowledge this is the cleanest way of having multiple processes write results in parallel to the same data structure.  I wish the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html had an example like this.

***Note*** the order of the result list will usually not match the order of the input list, a different approach would be needed if order had to be maintained.

Comment: imho, the accepted answer is simple to understand, short, and self contained - exactly what the person setting this up for the first time needs.