# Python multiprocessing processes terminating?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I've read a number of answers here on Stackoverflow about Python multiprocessing, and I think this one is the most useful for my purposes: [python multiprocessing queue implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363237/python-multiprocessing-queue-implementation).

Here is what I'd like to do: poll the database for new work, put it in the queue and have 4 processes continuously do the work. What I'm unclear on is what happens when an item in the queue is done being processed. In the question above, the process terminates when the queue is empty. However, in my case, I'd just like to keep waiting until there is data in the queue. So do I just sleep and periodically check the queue? So my worker processes will never die? Is that good practice?

```
def mp_worker(queue):
    while True:
        if (queue.qsize() == 0):
            time.sleep(20)
        else:
            db_record = queue.get()
            process_file(db_record)

def mp_handler():
    num_workers = 4
    processes = [Process(target=mp_worker, args=(queue,)) for _ in range(num_workers)]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_conn = db.create_postgre_connection(DB_CONFIG)
    while True:
        db_records = db.retrieve_received_files(DB_CONN)
        if (len(db_records) > 0):
            for db_record in db_records:
                queue.put(db_record)
                mp_handler()
        else:
            time.sleep(20)


    db_conn.close()
```

Does it make sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Workers have to die, since otherwise they never return. But I start a new set of workers when there is data anyway, so that's not a problem. Updated code:

```
def mp_worker(queue):
    while queue.qsize() > 0 :
        db_record = queue.get()
        process_file(db_record)

def mp_handler():
    num_workers = 4
    if (queue.qsize() < num_workers):
        num_workers = queue.qsize()
    processes = [Process(target=mp_worker, args=(queue,)) for _ in range(num_workers)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        db_records = db.retrieve_received_files(DB_CONN)
        print(db_records)
        if (len(db_records) > 0):
            for db_record in db_records:
                queue.put(db_record)
                mp_handler()
        else:
            time.sleep(20)

    DB_CONN.close()
```